# Reverse engineer CRC Canbus

Tags: crc

I am trying to figure out what I believe is a CRC8 value on some 8 byte canbus messages.
I have tried "RevEng" without luck.
But maybe some of you are able to figure it out.

Some messages in hex;

```
27717DFDFFFF4EE7

27717DFDFFFF4F2C

27717DFDFFFF5049

27717DFDFFFF5182

27297CFCFFFF8528

27DA7BFDFFFF86DB
```

The first 6 bytes are data, the 7th byte I believe is just an incrementer and the 8th byte is what i believe is an CRC calculation.

Anyone that can find the pattern?

Comment: Can you explain more what you have done using reveng? Only tested the full data (7 bytes) or also some reduced variants such as taking out first byte? Can you create and post more consecutive samples to verify that CRC is theoretically an option?